# Publishing Windows Phone 8 apps with sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, release

Considering that an app using a sqlite db, needs to be build for x86 platforms in order to run on the emulator and under ARM in order to get deployed on a device.

The question is, how does one publish a WP8 app with a sqlite database? Under which active solution platform in the configuration manager menu should the project be build in order to pass the store verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When publishing to the store you publish the ARM version, because that is the only version that can work on an actual device.

Just set the Build Configuration to target ARM and set it to Release. Then look in the Bin/ARM/Release folder for the .xap package.

Comment: isn't intel meant to release a x86-powered windows phone?

Comment: Right, my bad. I was selecting the Release configuration on the Solution level, without adding the necessary `USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE` Conditional compilation symbol on the project properties for the release. This made the build come up with a bunch of errors. Thanks.

Comment: @zaitsman - I am wondering what happens when an x86 phone hits the market as well but at least for now good to know its all ARM.